# How to perform a custom sort on an array and preserve keys

Tags: php, arrays

So I currently have this:

```
array(0=>'foo', 1=>'bar', 3=>'baz', 4=>'boo', 5=>'wahoo');
```

What I want is this:

```
array(0=>'foo', 3=>'baz', 1=>'bar', 5=>'wahoo', 4=>'boo');
```

This is a simplified example, my actual array is much larger and more complex so it can't easily be broken into smaller pieces and re-assembled.

I've been using uksort to attempt this, which I think is the best way forward but can't seem to get the results I want.

Edit:

I think my simplified example is actually confusing the issue. Here is my actual array and what I want to end up with.

```
Array
(
    [1820] => Safety
    [1821] => Security
    [1822] => Digital Life
    [1893] => Privacy and Digital Footprints
    [1823] => Connected Culture
    [1824] => Respecting Creative Work
    [1825] => Searching
    [1826] => Research and Evaluation
    [1836] => Self-Expression and Identity
)

Array
(
    [1820] => Safety
    [1821] => Security
    [1822] => Digital Life
    [1893] => Privacy and Digital Footprints
    [1823] => Connected Culture
    [1836] => Self-Expression and Identity
    [1824] => Respecting Creative Work
    [1825] => Searching
    [1826] => Research and Evaluation
)
```

So I almost have a numeric sort with two items pulled out of sequence.

Comment: Is it a numerical or associative array?

Comment: @Jared - as soon as the keys are out of order it is associative (technically it's always associative with some special handling when php sees numbers).

Comment: What is the sort criteria? E.g. Why is baz to be before bar but boo behind wahoo?

Comment: Is there any logic to the order of your items?  Or do you want to manually change the order of some items to whatever position you want while keeping their keys?

Comment: No logic, just want to move some items out of the initial sort order based on client's sense of how important they are, and the keys are important for later processing.

Comment: In that case, I highly recommend creating a better question that much more accurately reflects what you want to do.  Here are some other options:  First, use what is here and make the compare function aware of the priorities of each item.  Second, change your data structure to include the priorities and sort by them in the compare function.

Comment: Making the compare function aware of the priorities is where I'm stuck. As far as I can tell I should be able to do it with either uasort or uksort. Unfortunately in this case changing the data structure isn't possible without creating hours of work on either side of this piece.

Comment: Are all of the keys "known" in advance?  Are you able to list all occurring keys in your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer based on discussion.

Do use `uksort()`

Do a switch in the compare function for the ones that match and change them.

Example that works for your example above.

```
function updateKey($key)
{
   switch($key)
   {
     case 1893:
       return 1822.5;

     case 1836:
       return 1823.5;

     default:
       return $key;
   }
}

function cmp($a, $b) 
{
    $a = updateKey($a);
    $b = updateKey($b);

    // you must do the compare this way for floats (instead of just subtracting) because php implemented the compare callback poorly
    if ($a == $b) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

uksort($array, 'cmp');
```

Answer (score 2):

You're actually looking for [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

That will let you use your own sorting function and preserve the keys.

`uksort` sorts based on the keys, not the values.

Example:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/E8oZ2g

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Array to be sorted
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'b');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

// Sort and print the resulting array
uasort($array, 'cmp');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => b
)

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [3] => b
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```

Comment: Will it preserve numeric indices?

Comment: In the example, keys move with the values.  That's what uasort does see the added example.

Comment: True (as you see, I was wondering about it). The only thing I'd add is that a `foreach()` loop is required to access the new array's order: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kQuwis. (And I would prefer your code in the answer too, not just in the codepad page, but `+1` anyway.)

Comment: so if I want to end up with `code`array(0=>'foo', 5=>'wahoo', 1=>'bar', 3=>'baz', 4=>'boo');`code` as my final result using uasort how do I proceed. As I understand it `code`if($a == 'wahoo') return -1`code` should float it all the way to the top, but how do I stop at a certain point?

Comment: You can't "stop" the sorting.  If you have some special algorithm that does the sorting, you put that as the compare function.  But it must work when comparing each value to each other value.

Comment: @MarkFerree: To "stop" sorting, you should specifiy in your question the criteria and that you want to do it, because right now it's not clear that you ask for it ;)

Comment: Updated the question with the actual criteria.

Comment: @Mark - added a new answer based on this discussion

Answer (score 0):

```
//randomize array preserving keys
function shuffle_assoc( $array )
{
   $keys = array_keys( $array );
   shuffle( $keys );
   return array_merge( array_flip( $keys ) , $array );
}
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Note that this returns a new array, it doesn't modify the input array.

Comment: Sorry, I think the random in the title threw it off, the items which move are important. I meant that the resulting order wasn't predictable in any way.

Comment: What kind of formula or function do you want to use to go from the original array to the result array? are they sorted in any particular order or are you just assigning them manually?